# Error: Oracle 280000, Account is unlocked

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I am trying to connect Oracle database in SSRS. After entering username, datasource, password it is showing as ORA-28000.

[image]

But I am able to connect to Oracle using the same credentials in Oracle Sql Developer so I am not sure whats the issue with connecting in SSRS Datasource.

How can I fix this?

I checked in the database and the user account status is open.

Comment: I always hated connecting to Oracle DBs because of these issues. This sounds similar - will No Creds work? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cf089f0e-9da4-43d5-a488-d47614dbab08/ssrs-odbc-to-oracle-not-connecting?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: @HannoverFist - Thanks for response.But I don't see any one facing similar issue in the link provided.